# Project structure focus update when editing a file

Tags: clion

In CLion, is there a way to force it to highlight the file you are editing in the project structure? For example, if I follow some definition, it'd be great for me to see in which project the corresponding .h file resides. The same for the #include'd files: it goes to the file, but I have no idea where it is actually on disk, in which of 80+ projects it resides!

Comment: How is this a C++ question? How is this a Linux question?

Comment: @thorka corrected, sorry about that. I am just really in a rush with this one, since I have to work with some legacy code of >20,000 files, so if need be I'll propose a bounty as big as I can afford :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the project view, click on the little cog symbol and select either of `Autoscroll [to|from] source`.

The effect is fairly self-explanatory:

- from source means that the project tree is updated accordingly when you open or change the current source file in the editor by some means. Following a symbol with `F12` is fairly prominent, but also simply switching the tab results in project tree changes. The three is traversed and nodes with children are expanded accordingly.
- vice versa, to source means that changing the selection in the tree will result in opening the file in the editor or changing to the corresponding, existing tab.

All of the above is also dependent on the current view in the editor when working with split views, i.e. if you select some open document in some view the tree and this particular view are synced.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to focus just a single file, perform `Select In... | Project View` action (`Alt-F1` + `Enter` by default).